# Id input form same with name form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a form input with `id` and `name` like this

```
<?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'date','name'=>'datefrom', 'data-format' => 'YY-MM-DD', 'data-template' => 'YY MM DD', 'id'=> 'datefrom', 'placeholder'=>'Date From', 'class'=>'form-control', 'value'=> set_value('datefrom'))); ?>
```

and the result when I opened in browser is `<input name="datefrom" value="" id="datefrom" data-format="YY-MM-DD" data-template="YY MM DD" placeholder="Date From" class="form-control" type="text">`

the `Id` and `name` is same name. like this picture:[image]

I want `id` is "date", and `name` is "datefrom". But I don't want use manual input form like this.

```
<input name="datefrom" value="" id="date" .....>
```

I want use datas form with array. Please help..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `id` twice in your array, so old one overwritten, remove `'id'=> 'datefrom',` from your array

```
<?php echo form_input(
 array('id'=>'date',
       'name'=>'datefrom', 
       'data-format' => 'YY-MM-DD', 
       'data-template' => 'YY MM DD', 


       'id'=> 'datefrom',
       /* ^
          | 
          Here you replaced with new values, thats why, both name and 
          id attributes are datefrom 
          remove this 'id' => 'datefrom'
       */ 
       'placeholder'=>'Date From', 
       'class'=>'form-control', 
       'value'=> set_value('datefrom')
    )
); ?>
```

Comment: thank you, but I need "name" and "id" but I want, id and name is deffrent value.

Comment: @AbedPutra That is exactly what the above answer will give you. As it states... In Many Places - remove 'id'=>'datefrom' from the array... You have defined id TWICE!

Comment: you defined key `id` twice in your array, please remove second one

Answer (score 1):

Use this one.

```
<?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'date','name'=>'datefrom', 'data-format' => 'YY-MM-DD', 'data-template' => 'YY MM DD', 'placeholder'=>'Date From', 'class'=>'form-control', 'value'=> set_value('datefrom'))); ?>
```